# JS use pre-arranged numbers/letters from a list instead of generating letters/numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, get

For example:

```
for (var x=iFirst; x<=iLast; x++) {
var s = "GET " + 
        sBase.Replace("##", 4 + Math.random().toString().substr(2, 6)) + 
        " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"; 
}
```

Will replace a string of characters with a random 7 digit number beginning with 4. As long as iFirst is less than iLast it will repeat.

I'd like to to the same thing, except instead of generating random numbers. Use number from a pre-compiled list such as:
1234567
1234367
1234377
1434377

Alternatively, I'd like to replace ## with a snippet of text, spaces and special characters, such as:
holl"a back'
Hoot & "sc99t
M7ss :piggy "hot"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var num_list = [1234567 1234367 1234377 1434377];
for (var x=iFirst; x<=iLast; x++) {
var s = "GET " + 
        sBase.Replace("##", 4 + num_list[x-iFirst]) + 
        " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I guess I figured this out.

```
var do_array = new Array();

    do_array[0] = "loot";
    do_array[1] = "boo\"rua t";
    do_array[2] = "srt";

for (var x=iFirst; x<=iLast; x++) {
var s = "GET " + sBase.Replace("##", do_array[x]) + " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"; 
}
```